# polling subprocess in python yields unexpected results

Tags: python

I have this loop to check whether a `subprocess` has finished, but it gets stuck in the loop forever:

```py
 process = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split("kubectl logs -f {} -n {} -c {}"
                                   .format(pod_name, namespace, application)),
                                   stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        while True:
            output = process.stdout.readline()
            # click.echo(process.poll())
            if output == "" and process.poll() is not None:
                break
            if output:
                click.echo(output.strip())
        rc = process.poll()
```

The weird part is that by trial and error I came to realise that

```py
output == ""
```

is the one that does not evaluate to true.

However that weird thing returned by

```py
output = process.stdout.readline()
```

is of **zero** length?

How is this possible?

What is this thing that has zero length but fails to pass the test

```py
output == ""
```

Comment: Try checking `output is None`. IIRC `.readline()` returns `None` when there's nothing left to read from the file, as opposed to an empty string (which it would return if there were no text on the line). You could encompass both the checks with `if not output`, if that works

Comment: I have tried, this also returns `False`

Comment: `if not output` did the job however; still makes me wonder what is this zero-length thing returned that fails to `thing == ''`

Comment: Could be a text/binary encoding issue. Usually the streams are opened in binary mode by default, so the correct test should be `output == b''`.

Comment: just a note. the condition `output == ""` used to work in Python 2.7; the issue appeared as I am porting my code to Python 3.7